# Can't update to rails 4.1: Conflict with simple_form

Tags: simple-form, ruby-on-rails-4.1

When updating from rails from 4.0 to 4.1, I stumbled in the following dependency problem:

```
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    simple_form (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activemodel (< 4.1, >= 4.0.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.1.0) ruby depends on
      activemodel (4.1.0)
```

How can I install `rails 4.1` with `simple_form`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the github version, since the rubygems one don't seems to work.
On your gemfile, update the `simple_form` to:

```
gem 'simple_form', github: 'plataformatec/simple_form'
```

Source: [google groups in a language which I can't read](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-tr/01Wojco_aKE)